# Maximum data a GPU can take?

Tags: memory, memory-management, cuda, bigdata, ram

I have a large dataset, say, 5 GB and I am doing *stream*-wise processing on the data, now, I need to figure out on how much data I can send to GPU at a time for processing, so that I can make utilization of GPU memory to the fullest.

Also, if my RAM is not sufficient to do processing/hold on 5 GB of data, what is the work-around for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The maximum amount of data you can send to the GPU is equivalent to it's video RAM (minus whatever amount is already in use).

Comment: But streams in CUDA are to rescue there which provides asynchronous transfer of data. My question elaborately asks taking account the streams, what is the usable memory of GPU? How can I unveil that? DeviceQuery or some other thing in CUDA?

Btw, why downvoted w/o understanding the depth of the question?

Comment: Apologies then :/
But did you get what I intend to ask?

Comment: I do, but I've never used CUDA so I'm out of my depth here. Hope you find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pipelined application might use 3 buffers on the GPU.  One buffer is used to hold the data currently being *transferred to* the GPU (from the host), one buffer to hold the data currently being *processed by* the GPU, and one buffer to hold the data(results) currently being *transferred from* the GPU (to the host).

This implies that your application processing can be broken into "chunks".  This is true for many applications that work on large data sets.

CUDA [streams](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) enable the developer to write code that allows these 3 operations (transfer to, process, transfer from) to run simultaneously.

There is no specific number that defines the size of the buffers in the above scenario.  Certainly, a straightforward implementation would create 3 buffers, each of which is smaller than 1/3 of the total memory on the GPU, leaving some memory left over for overhead and other data that may need to live in GPU memory.  So if your GPU has 5GB, you might be able to run with three 1GB buffers.  But there is no tool like `deviceQuery` that will tell you this; it is not a property of the device.

You may want to read carefully the above linked programming guide section, as well as review the CUDA [simple streams](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simplestreams) sample code.

Comment: Let's say my RAM has 4 GB of memory, my GPU 1 GB and my data 32 GB. Except loading the program in RAM in batches and running the CUDA program over and over again, is there some other workaround of doing this? Because, this can kill the performance.

Comment: You will certainly have to break your data up into pieces.  But if the amount of computation you have to do is enough, the data loading time can be "hidden" by the computation time, in a properly pipelined algorithm.  By allowing data copy to occur simultaneously with compute, it's often possible to "hide" the data copy time since the GPU is busy computing.